# visual studio 2010 using SQLCe 3.5 but project has 4.4 sdf file

Tags: windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce, versioning

I have added sql compack edition v4.0 file on my windows phone 7 project in visual studio 2010. I copied the data base from application folder to isolated storage, now while querying it gives this thing

```
countyList.Count()
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.Data.Internal.dll
'countyList.Count()' threw an exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException'
    base {System.Data.Common.DbException}: {"Incompatible Database Version. If this was a compatible file, run repair. For other cases refer to documentation. [ Db version = 4000000,Requested version = 3505053,File name = AMEDatabase.sdf ]"}
    _customMessage: "Incompatible Database Version. If this was a compatible file, run repair. For other cases refer to documentation. [ Db version = 4000000,Requested version = 3505053,File name = AMEDatabase.sdf ]"
    _errors: {System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeErrorCollection}
    Errors: {System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeErrorCollection}
    HResult: -2147467259
    Message: "Incompatible Database Version. If this was a compatible file, run repair. For other cases refer to documentation. [ Db version = 4000000,Requested version = 3505053,File name = AMEDatabase.sdf ]"
    NativeError: 28609
    Source: "SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider"
```

when i added this file from my visual studio how this thing can use 3.5 version??
what to do? could it be coz the System.Data.Linq file?(my project has v 2.0 of this dll)

Comment: Windows Phone only Works with 3.5 databases

Comment: @ErikEJ Please post ur comment as an answer so that i can select it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use SQL Servver Compact verision 3.5 databases with Windows Phone

Answer (score -1):

We need some settings to use sql ce v4.0 in VS 2010, hit googles for more info.

Comment: That i know and i'm searching it over net for a long time from now